# Запрос со значением null в свойстве в neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Я работаю с Neo4j, у меня есть узлы, которые представляют события, которые происходят в жизни пользователей, такие как дни рождения, экзамены и т. Д. Некоторые из этих событий имеют дату истечения срока действия, а другие нет, мне нужно показать события, что дата истечения срока действия больше, чем текущая дата или у которой нет даты истечения срока действия, то есть она является  `null`, поскольку я ее понимаю в Neo4j нельзя определить свойства с значением `null`, в этом случае это узел, который не имеет этого свойства, но тогда как я могу построить запрос, в котором я нуждаюсь ?, то есть это было бы примерно так: `match (e: Event), where e.dueAt <132456790 or e.dueAt = null return e`, но этот запрос неверен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хотя сервер Neo4j не сохраняет свойства с нулевыми значениями, если он может быть отфильтрован ими, запрос будет выглядеть так: `match (e: Event), where e.dueAt <132456790 or e.dueAt IS NULL return e`